# Display file.pdf As a Blob

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, blob

I am working on different ways of displaying a PDF to get better on a project at work.  I am able to insert a url to a PDF into an iframe element and it displays the PDF fine.  Sometimes we have a use case where the front end receives a pdf as application/pdf instead of a url in a json object.

For this, I turn the application/pdf into a blob and create a url for the blob. This worked great on everything except Android, so I am testing out some methods with iFrame.

I would like to take this sample pdf http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf, turn it into a blob, and insert the blob url in the src of an iframe element for the purposes of testing blobs as iframe sources on Android Chrome browsers.

```
function App() {
  const samplePdf = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"

  const blob = new Blob([samplePdf], { type: 'application/pdf' });

  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

  return (
    <>
      <h1>iFrame Rendering of PDF Blob</h1>
      <iframe title="pdf" src={url} style={{ height: '1250px', width: '100%' }}></iframe>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[This is what renders in the React app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6BwM.png)

What am I missing to get the content of the pdf to display?  React is not a requirement, just seemed an easy way to start a quick practice project.

Comment: This reads like it could be an  [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you report having issues under android with blob URLs , but post a "solution" example that doesn't work on any platform, and is attracting answers that require `createObjectURL` to work. You may two questions, but please consider asking and providing details of the android problem first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the data to construct the blob while the URL just points to the data you need. Let's go & get it:

```js
const getLocalPdfUrl = async () => {
  const url = 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf';

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await response.blob();

  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
```

This function returns a `Promise` that will (hopefully) resolve with the URL you can use to construct the iframe. It's `async`, so, don't forget to wait for the promise to resolve.

**Testing note**
Fetching external resources from the frontend is restricted by CORS, so, pdf995.com's link will **not** work. It's also not a trivial task to find a dummy PDF document that would allow fetching itself from the FE.

To test if it works, I'd propose to place the PDF file in the `/public` folder (or similar) & serve it on the same localhost as the app.

Comment: This did work for getting the blob, but the iFrame content with blob source does not show up on any mobile browser.